# Spot repair wood surface of dresser

Tags: repair, wood, wooden-furniture

We had a sock with those little rubber/sticky grips sitting on this dresser for a while now.
This evening after a doing a whole house cleaning I happened to notice a small spot on the dresser and after picking up the sock saw these small "potholes" where it was sitting.

How could I go about spot fixing these pot marks?
I'm not looking for perfect but just want it to blend in a bit.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might try a colored wood oil product, like this stuff:

[image]

I have had good luck with blending out small nicks and scratches. Won't be perfect but easier than a complete refinish.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion.
There is still some gunk from the pads on the bottom of the socks still stuck to the surface. I would assume it would be wise to remove that before trying this cover up. Any recommendations for removing that? Would something like Goo Gone be good?

Comment: Goo Gone or any other solvent product may smear the finish, perhaps tragically. On the other hand, on lacquer based finishes I have in the past used a small amount of lacquer thinner to blend away scratches and nicks by smearing the finish. I don't recommend trying it though, at least not without testing on an inconspicuous area. Try warm soapy water to remove the rubber dabs.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like mahogany… I agree with previous commenter’ answer, but you might want to get a specific mahogany scratch fix like this: http://www.howardproducts.com/product/restor-a-finish/